# napili template vf page issue showing disabled

Tags: community

The vf page is getting disabled when I am using the same in napili template.I have follwed https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_visualforce.htm but still no luck

Comment: Did you add the VF page to the Community sites?. If not it will not show up when you see if from inside community

Comment: I added it but still the page is coming within a greyed out area

Comment: @RedDevil :I added it but still the page is coming within a greyed out area

Comment: Do you get any error messages? It would be useful to try getting the developer console output in the browser and the SF debug log for the user to see if there are any messages showing.

Comment: no error message...it doesn't look like vf pages are supported in napili template

Comment: VF definitely works in Napili as I am using both my own and an AppExchange app with VF pages in.

Comment: apart from other the vf pages in the profiles and site....is there any other thing which needs to be done?

Comment: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://lightningwebsite-dev-ed--livepreview.ap2.force.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://lightningwebsite-dev-ed--sitestudio.ap2.force.com'). ---This error I am getting in console

Comment: a grey backgrund is coming behind the vf page and the vf page is also not scrollable